# suds-jurko api error message

Tags: python, django, netsuite, suds

i have the following piece of code using suds-jurko used to interface with Netsuite

```
    try:
        search_response = client.service.searchMoreWithId(search_id, page_index)
    except:
        print 'NOTHING LEFT'
        break
    else:
        success = search_response.status._isSuccess
        if success:
            <do something on success>
        else:
            print 'FAIL'
            break
```

when i execute this code, the print "FAIL" executes. i wish to check what specific error occured which caused search_response.status._isSuccess to return False but i'm not sure where to check. I was looking for something like an error message in the structure of the SearchResult object of suds so i could find why it returned a fail but i don't see a property or function for this. Where could i begin checking?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but there were records with fields that had errors in them in Netsuite. What i did was to break down the calls to have fewer records per page so if an error occurs on a page fetch, i could query each record individually from that page and find the ones with errors. Those records were fixed and the fetching proceeded properly